# ios - can't get css file styles to render in HTML from a UIWebView

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview

If I create inline styles they render, but when try to reference a css file in the same group and directory within xCode, they do not render.

Here is what I do:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Hello, world! Learn</h1>

    <p>
    <a href="myscheme://advertising" class="buttonStyle">Click me!</a>
    </p> 
</body>
</html>
```

and then I have the css file called main.css like this:

```
body {background-color:#b0c4de;}
p {background-color:#e0ffff;}
```

Would anyone know why this would not render the css? Am I missing something important from the HTML header?

Here is how I call the HTML in the first place:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"learn" 
                                                         ofType:@"html"];

    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [theWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:htmlFile]];

    [theWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in

```
[theWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Since baseURL is nil, the web view has no way to determine where your css file is. Instead of messing with manually creating data and loading it, pass the path of the HTML file directly to the UIWebView:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"learn" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
NSURLRequest *rq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:rq];
```

Comment: Thanks... Its a WOW. But my case is little different. My css files are in the css folder. And I am accessing it as css/style.css. In this case its still not accessing the css. Whereas if i put the css out of the folder and access as style.css only its working. Can you help me out. The reason I need to put in respective folder is because to prevent future mess. Please help.

Comment: Is it necessary to have all the css, html, js files in one folder or can they be split into different folders?

Comment: @Satyamsvv They can be in different folders, as long as you reference them correctly (using relative paths) from within your HTML, CSS or JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks so much. but if im using a POST request for the page, do you have any idea how can i achieve this